# Prove that if $g \circ f$ is onto and $g$ is one-to-one, then $f$ is onto

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$ be maps. Prove that if $g \circ f$ is onto and $g$ is one-to-one, then $f$ is onto.

**Attempt:**

If $g \circ f$ is onto, then for all $y \in A$, $\exists x$ such that $y = g(f(x))$. If $g$ is one-to-one then if $g(x_1) = g(x_2)$, $x_1 = x_2$. Thus, there are no two $f(x)$'s for some $y$ such that $y = g(f(x))$.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of onto mixes up the domain and codomain, and you don't seem to be proving that $f$ is onto.

---

Choose any $b \in B$. We seek some $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$. To this end, let $c = g(b)$. Since $g \circ f$ is onto, we know that there is some $a \in A$ such that $g(f(a)) = c$. In other words, $g(f(a)) = g(b)$. But since $g$ is one-to-one, we conclude that $f(a) = b$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

**Proof:**    for any $y\in B$, $g(y) \in C$; since  $g \circ f$ is onto, then there exists $x \in A$ such that $g \circ f (x) =g(f(x))=g(y)$. Note that $g$ is one to one, therefore  $f(x)=y$; this shows that $f$ is onto.